# Why is flutter not running on android device when flutter doctor is clean and USB debugging is on?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, daemon

I upgraded my flutter sdk from 3.0 to the latest 3.16.5. Since then I can't run any flutter apps on my Android device. The project works perfectly on chrome. I don't think this is the cause of the problem but I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Could not write standard input to Gradle Worker Daemon 1.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Failed to run Gradle Worker Daemon
    > Process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

What can be the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can add your gradle, java and the AS version for better debugging.